# Can't get two functions to initialize each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function funcA() {
 var fB;

 function init() {
  fB = new funcB(false); //error here
 }

 init();
}

function funcB(usefuncA) {
 var fA;

 function init() {
  if (usefuncA) fA = new funcA();
 }

 init();
}

$(function() {
 var test = new funcB(true);
});
```

I know how to get around this problem in C++, but no idea what tricks there are to fix it in javascript.  There is a way, though, right?  I absolutely must have each function in the other, and the only other alternative I can think of is putting the contents of funcB in its own .js file then using PHP to create two versions of funcB, one for funcA to use and one in current place of funcB.  But that's ridiculous...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? I am absolutely sure there's a better way.

Comment: They both wrap a jQuery interface.  funcB is sort of a search function with multiple options, one of which is funcA.  funcA, however, also needs to be able to use a slightly more limited funcB to search for data to grab for its own functionality.  The funcB that funcA will initialize won't allow for an infinite loop, btw, the slight limitation is that it won't use funcA, but lots of other stuff that it has in both cases.  I really would like to it similar to what I have outlined in the OP, not really looking for a solution that changes everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code (your original code, minus the unneeded call to jquery) works fine for me. There's no error.

You can run it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KHpHd/) (take a look at the console).

```
function funcA() {
 var fB;

 function init() {
  fB = new funcB(false); //error here
 }

 init();
}

function funcB(usefuncA) {
 var fA;

 function init() {
  if (usefuncA) fA = new funcA();
 }

 init();
}

var test;

test = new funcA();

console.log(test);

test = new funcB();

console.log(test);

test = new funcB(true);

console.log(test);
```

​

Answer (score 0):

```
  (function (testFuncA, $, undefined) {
       testFuncA.init = function(caller) { // do stuff  },
  } (window.testFuncA= window.testFuncA|| {}, jQuery));

  (function (testFuncB, $, undefined) {
       testFuncB.init = function() { testFuncA.init(this);  },
  } (window.testFuncB= window.testFuncB|| {}, jQuery));
```

Do you mean something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid the infinite loop.

```
function funcA(B) {
 var fB;
 var that = this;
 function init() {
    fB = B || new funcB(that);
 }
 init();
}

function funcB(A) {
 var fA;
 var that = this;
 function init() {
   fA = A || new funcA(that);
 }
 init();
}

$(function() {
 var test = new funcB();
});​
```

Comment: Avoiding the infinite loop doesn't fix the problem, it still breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function funcA() {
    var fB;

    this.init = function() {
        fB = new funcB(false); //error here
    }
}

function funcB(usefuncA) {
    var fA;

    this.init = function init(usefuncA) {
        if (usefuncA) fA = new funcA();
    }
}

$(function() {
    var test = new funcB();
    test.init(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it maybe this what you are looking for?

```
FuncA = function () {
       var fB; this.init(); };
FuncA.prototype.init = function () {
       this.fB = new FuncB(false); };
FuncB = function (usefuncA) {
       var fA; this.init(usefuncA); };
FuncB.prototype.init = function (usefuncA) { 
       var fA; if (usefuncA) { this.fA = new FuncA(); } };

var test = new FuncB(true);
```